# Google Cloud Debug not working with jar file "File was not found in the executable"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, executable-jar, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-debugger

I have been trying google cloud Debugger, i was able to get debugger hooked up in my source code, but whenever i put a breakpoint it throws as error "File was not found in the executable". I have also attached the screenshot for the same.
[Screenshot for Cloud Debug in Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFhj0.png)

For testing i am using Dropwizard Example, i am running below command to deploy my jar file on Google compute instance.

> java $( sudo ./format_env_gce.sh --app_class_path=path/to/jarfile --version=1.0.0 ) -jar -Done-jar.silent=true path/to/jarfile server config.yml

For above command i have been following link https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/setting-up-on-compute-engine

Please help me understand what am i missing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was more specific to my jar which i built using gradle, i have tried another way by using maven to create the jar and it works now.